# How to register module

Tags: node.js, require, rethinkdb, aurelia

I testing Aurelia framework and RethinkDB.
How can I register Require and RethinkDB to access them from Aurelia ?

```
import {require} from "require" //require.js is missing

r = require("rethinkdb"); // require is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the ES6 module system's `import` syntax removes the need to use requirejs and the `require` function. SystemJS which Aurelia uses in the sample skeleton application can handle AMD formatted modules (which is the format Require uses).

That being said, rethinkdb would be on your server, not on the client, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Possible it should be on server, because it is a JavaScript driver. But, I can't see how can I could connect to this driver from my website, and get data. Everywhere I saw rql tutorial. So I decided to install this driver on node where I testing Aurelia-skeleton. Server is on virtual machine on Ubuntu OS.

Comment: http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install-drivers/javascript/ I could make a mistake, but here is said the client driver - so I think, that I can add this to my app project. Unfortunately If I use import {rethinkdb} from 'rethinkdb' I go error 'missing  /dist/rethinkdb.js'. I try to map rethinkdb in config.js, but now he can't find events.js

Comment: The instructions on that page are for accessing a rethinkdb from a nodejs server app. You won't directly access rethinkdb from your client side code, you would wrap an API running on your server around the rethinkdb queries.

Comment: In that case I should have prepared views on server side, create application which will be listening network connection, and invoking rql query, line a bridge between rethinkdb and my client app? It is not convenient, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
import require from "require";
```

This would import the entire require module and doesn't expect an export named "require".